# Two-party equality computation

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs

Alice and Bob each secretly chooses an integer between 1 and 10, `a` and `b`. They want to know (with high probability) whether or not `a` equals `b`, without revealing any other information. Can they?

Comment: See this and its references. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires

Comment: crossposted [from mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/236473/5810) after less than 5 minutes, without mentioning that on either site ​ ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure they can, it's called the [socialist millionaires problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires). The most common solution is to use Yao's protocol: Alice sends a [garbled circuit](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/Yao's_garbled_circuit) of the equality function to Bob, and then Alice use [oblivious transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) to send the keys necessary for the evaluation of the circuit to Bob. Another option is to rely on additively homomorphic IND-CPA encryption: Alice sends an encryption $E(a)$ of her input $a$, Bob computes $E(r\cdot (a-b))$ from this ciphertext, using his input $b$ and a uniformly random value (over the plaintext space of the scheme) $r$. Alice decrypts and outputs yes if the result is 0, and no otherwise. As the scheme is IND-CPA, Bob learns nothing on Alice's input (the protocol is therefore computationally private for Alice); because of the random coin $r$, the decrypted value statistically masks $b$ when $a \neq b$ (the protocol is therefore statistically private for Bob).